# Accessing Google Sheets from Chrome extension via Chrome Identity API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to read data from a Google Sheet via a Chrome extension leveraging Chrome Identity API, but I'm not even able to get an access token. This is what I've done so far:

- Created an OAuth 2 client ID in Google API Console. Entered "http://localhost" and "https://localhost" in the authorized JavaScript origins (since my extension is in localhost for now).
- Updated the Chrome extension's `manifest.json` to include:

```
{
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/"
  ],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<enter-oauth2-client-id-here>",
    "scopes": [
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets"   
    ]
  }
}
```

- Added the following code in a background script

```
console.log("here"); // this point is hit

var ci = chrome.identity;
ci.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function(token) {
    console.log("token: " + token); // none of this is hit
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        return;
    }
    access_token = token;
});
```

At this point, when I reload the extension, Chrome asks me for my credentials (the `ci.getAuthToken({ interactive: true } ...)` line is executed), but once the credentials are successfully provided, nothing else happens. I guess the token is never retrieved, which is why none of the code within `function(token){...}` is executed. The background console shows the "here" message, but nothing else (no errors, warnings, or anything).

Note: In my `manifest.json`, under `oauth2:client_id` I'm using the OAuth2 client Id generated by the Google API Console.

What am I missing?

Comment: _"since my extension is in localhost for now"_ That doesn't make much sense. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: any progress with this one?

Comment: I have retrieved the token successfully but there's no progress when accessing the Google sheets.

Answer (score 1):

I think your [scope for spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#sheetsv4) is incorrect. It should be `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` based on its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing).

So change

```
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets"
```

to

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but if anyone stumbles upon this post: regarding your CORS policy problem, you need to play with the `content_security_policy` in your `manifest.json` file, like so:

```
"content_security_policy":  "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'"
```