# Access Google API in Chrome Extension - do I need to set URLs in permissions in the manifest?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension which calls some Google APIs. These use the Chrome Identity API, are declared in the oauth2 section of the manifest, and are called using the fetch API, and work fine. When I first wrote this extension, I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250725/accessing-google-sheets-from-chrome-extension-via-chrome-identity-api?rq=1) for guidance, and have declared https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/ in the permissions section of the manifest. However, I'm wondering if this is in fact necessary - it gives a scary permissions warning - that the extension can change all data on docs.google.com - which is not in fact the case.

I tried removing the permission from the extension and it seems to work fine, but would like to know what the official/expected behaviour here is - are URL permissions in a chrome extension only for interacting with that page, or are they supposed to be for any web access the extension initiates?

Comment: If it works without this URL permission then you're fine.